# How to parse Array Nested Object Json to Kotlin with retrofit?

Tags: android, json, parsing, kotlin, retrofit

I Have Json like this

```
[
    {
    "attributes": {"OBJECTID": 18,"Country_Region": "US", "Last_Update": 1585366775000}
    },

    {
    "attributes": {"OBJECTID": 11, "Country_Region": "Italy", "Last_Update": 1585366764000}
    }

]
```

I've been making a class like this

[image: Response]

But I'm so confusing for access it to livedata use kotlin and make activity and view model like this.

[image: Activity and View Model]

And make Retrofit like this.
[image: ApiClient & Adapter]

But when i launch the app, recycler view it doesn't show anything.my question is about Is something wrong with my retrofit parse?

Comment: It seems your condition is wrong. If the result is not null, you are setting the visibility of RecyclerView equal to Gone. So you won't see anything when the request is successful.

Comment: @hosseinAmini Oh mannn, Thank you for your help, im not look for that!

Answer (score 0):

In your onResponse shouldn't it be the ArrayList being passed? I think you need to change your Retrofit Interface to use that^ instead.